# why some pooled variance has "average" and some just uses direct sum without avg?

Tags: variance, pooling

say $X,Y$ are two random variables. I see courses saying $X+Y$ and $X-Y$, each has a variance of $\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2.$

But, on the other hand, I also see courses talking about for $X$ and $Y,$ their pooled variance is $(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)/2,$ assuming 1) their having the same population variance; 2) same sample size for each so same weights; 3) ignore small difference in degrees of freedom (i.e., ignore the $-1).$

Now my question is why one says the variance is $\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2$ while the other takes an average: $(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)/2?$

which one is correct or maybe they are both correct but for different use cases?

Comment: iF $X$ and $Y$ are _independent_ random variables then $Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y).$ If `x` is a sample of $n_1$ observations from a population with variance $\sigma^2$ and `y` is an independentsample of size $n_2$ from a population with variance $\sigma^2,$ then the pooled estimate of $\sigma^2$ is $\frac{(n_1-1)S_1^2 + (n_2-1)S_2^2}{n_1+n_2 - 2},$ where $S_1^2, S_2^2$ are sample variances. In case $n_1=n_2,$ this simplifies to $\frac{S_1^2+S_2^2}{2}.$

Comment: @BruceET I think you can convert your comment into answer

Comment: Leaving Comment for reference. Answer below is essentially the same, except that the answer has a couple of examples.

Comment: this makes sense. then what this "pooled estimate" is about? it's not about the new random variable (X+Y) or (X-Y), right? then what is this about?

Answer (score 0):

**For random variables:** If $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables then $$Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y).$$

*Example:* Suppose A tosses a fair coin $n_1 = 12$ times and gets $X$ heads, then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(12, 0.5),$ which has mean $\mu_1 = E(X) = n_1p = n_1(.5) = 6$ and variance $\sigma_1 = n_1p(1-p) = (12)(1/4) = 3.$

Also, suppose, independently, B tosses a fair coin $n_2 = 16$ times and obtains $Y$ heads with $\mu_2 = 8, \sigma_2 = 4.$

Then the number of heads from both A and B together has distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(28, .5)$ with mean $\mu = \mu_1+\mu_2 = 6 + 8 = 14$
and variance $\sigma = \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 =
3 + 4 = 7$, which is also $\mu = 28(.5) = 14$ and
$\sigma^2 = 28(.5)(.5) = 28/4 = 7.$

**For data:** If `x` is a sample of $n_1$ observations from a population with variance $σ^2$ and `y` is an independent sample of size
$n-2$ from a population with variance $σ^2,$ then the pooled estimate of $σ^2$ is

$$\frac{(n_1−1)S_1^2+(n_2−1)S_2^2}{n_1+n_2−2},$$ where $S_1^2,S_2^2$ are sample variances.

In case $n_1=n_2,$ this simplifies to
$\frac{S_1^2+S_2^2}{2}.$

*Example:* Suppose you have sample `x` of size
$n_1 = 25$ from population A, with sample mean $\bar X = 28.3$ and sample variance $S_x^2 = 17.21$ (sample standard deviation $S_y = 4.148.)$

Also, you have sample `y` of size $n_1 = 25$ from population B, with sample mean $\bar Y = 35.7$ and sample varianse $S_y^2 = 18.08$ (sample standard deviation $S_y = 4.252.)$

If you know that both populations are normal, then you might want to do a pooled 2-sample t test of
$H_0: \mu_x = \mu_y$ against
$H_a: \mu_x \ne \mu_y.$

Then, the appropriate test statisic is
$T = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{S_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{25}}}.$

If we enter the sample sizes, sample means, and sample standard deviations into Minitab statistical software, then we get the following
output for the pooled 2-sample t test:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       25  28.30   4.15     0.83
2       25  35.70   4.25     0.85

 Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
 Estimate for difference:  -7.40
 95% CI for difference:  (-9.79, -5.01)

 T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
  T-Value = -6.23  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 48
  Both use Pooled StDev = 4.2003
```

Then the pooled standard deviation $S_p$ used
both for the confidence interval and the t statistic is
$$S_p = \sqrt{S_p^2}= \sqrt{\frac{S_1^2+S_2^2}{2}}.$$ from above.

Then $$S_p^2 = \frac{S_1^2 + S_2^2}{2} = \frac{17.21+18.08}{2} = \frac{15.29}{2} = 17.645.$$ So that $S_p =  4.200595$ which agrees with the
Minitab output, except for rounding used in the output.